# How to refresh an image in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I have a form with an Image widget and a FileUpload widget.
I can use file upolad to change images.

I'd like to visualise a changed image right after a new image is submited to a servlet. But how can I force an Image widget to grab a new image from server ? (image's url doesn't change, content does) .

Comment: That's a feature of the browser... Try adding some sort of unique string to the image's url every time it changes (a hash of current time in millies or the like).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can't/don't want to change the URL on the server, you can alternatively add a query parameter like:

```
version++;
image.setUrl(url + "?v" + version);
```

The query parameter will be ignored on the server (except if you want to use it somehow), but it forces a reload, because the browser doesn't know, if the image might be generated dynamically.

Comment: I realize your answer was nearly 9 years ago, but this helped me today.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Or better: just set the URL to "" then back to the original URL. Tested in Chrome.

```
String url = image.getUrl();
image.setUrl("");
image.setUrl(url);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, the image is not reloaded.